# Is there a way to get specified data through click event using tooltip function in d3 v6.1.1

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As per migration guide the click event have to show the data in the clicked bar.
Unable to get the error in this code:
https://codepen.io/bablu4195-1/pen/oNxGWRw

```
d3.on('click', (event,d,i)=> {
     tooltip.classList.add('show');
     tooltip.style.left = i * barWidth + padding * 2 + 'px';
     tooltip.style.top = height - padding * 4 + 'px';
     tooltip.innerHTML = `<small>${d[0]}</small>$${d[1]} billions`;
     tooltip.setAttribute("data-date", d[0]); 

     })
 .on('click', () => {
        tooltip.classList.remove('show')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have missed something about d3 scaling. Normally, you assign an object using `.data()`, like `.data([{ name: 'hello world', value: 12 }])`. However, you use `scaledGDP`, which means it has lost all other information and is just a number. If you use `GDP`, you can then access the scaled value using, for example, `rect.attr('height', function(d) return linearScale(d); })`.

Other than that, your tooltip didn't work for a couple of reasons. Firstly, you assigned `on('click')` twice. Once to add the tooltip and once to remove it. The second one overwrote the first. Secondly, you used `tooltip` like a HTML element, but it was a `d3` selection, so use `.classed()` instead of `classList()`, etc. Finally, as it said in the migration guide, `event` is now the first argument to the function, not `d`.

All this gives the following:

CSS:

```css
#tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
}
#tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
    .on("click", (event, d, i) => {
      if(!tooltip.classed("show")) {
        tooltip.classed("show", true)
          .html(`<small>${d[0]}</small>$${d[1]} billions`)
          .attr("data-date", d[0])
          .style("left", i * barWidth + padding * 2 + "px")
          .style("top", height - padding * 4 + "px");
      } else {
        tooltip.classed("show", false);
      }
    });
```

It doesn't yet fill the tooltip - because of the `scaledGDP` vs `GDP` thing, but it shows it and positions it.

Comment: .on('click', function(event, d,i) {
    var padding=40
    var height=400
    var barWidth=width/275;
      if(!tooltip.classed("show")) {
        tooltip.classed("show", true)
          .html(`<small>${d[0]}</small>$${d[1]} billions`)
          .attr("data-date", d[1])
          .style("left", i * barWidth + padding * 2 + "px")
          .style("top", height - padding * 4 + "px");
      } else {
        tooltip.classed("show", false);
      }         getting the result in console need it on Environment and sorry if its frustrating

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please don't get frustrated,the click event is not functioning and after evaluating found out that barWidth,padding,height variables are not defined. After defining them as per above code its error free but functionality is failing to show the specified bar data

Comment: I'm not frustrated, don't worry. I forked your codepen, have a look [here](https://codepen.io/rubenhelsloot/pen/eYZMZRy) for the working fix. I recommend using something like DiffChecker to see all the changes I made